# Integration with paygate in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment

So I have added the service reference to my project which is

```
https://secure.paygate.co.za/payhost/process.trans?wsdl
```

My PaygateRef is the web service reference Name(namespace)

```
PaygateRef.SinglePaymentRequest1 PaygatePayment = new PaygateRef.SinglePaymentRequest1();
PaygateRef.CardPaymentRequestType Request = new PaygateRef.CardPaymentRequestType();
Request.Account = new PaygateRef.PayGateAccountType();
Request.Account.PayGateId = "000000000";   //my PaygateID
Request.Account.Password = "mypassword";       //my Encryption key

Request.Customer = new PaygateRef.PersonType();
Request.Customer.Title = "Mr";
Request.Customer.FirstName = "Rich";
Request.Customer.LastName = "Buyer";
Request.Customer.Mobile = new string[]{"0830000001"}; //My cell number

Request.CardIssueNumber = "500000000000008";//card number
Request.CardIssueDate = "012020";//january 2020
Request.CVV = "001";// card ccv

Request.Order = new PaygateRef.OrderType();
Request.Order.MerchantOrderId = "115422488465";//a random test orderID
Request.Order.Currency = PaygateRef.CurrencyType.ZAR;
Request.Order.Amount = 100;  //R1

PaygatePayment.SinglePaymentRequest = new PaygateRef.SinglePaymentRequest();
PaygatePayment.SinglePaymentRequest.Item = Request;

PaygateRef.PayHOST myPaygateinterface = new PaygateRef.PayHOSTClient();

myPaygateinterface.SinglePayment(PaygatePayment);
```

The error I am getting is

```
Validation error
```

I tested with multiple cards that work on other sites 
and this account was used on the website previously written in PHP where it was working. 
So everything on Paygate side is set up correctly as per my understanding

Why am i getting this error and how do I solve it?

**Edited** 
I did try

```
Request.ItemsElementName = new PaygateRef.ItemsChoiceType[]
{
    PaygateRef.ItemsChoiceType.CardExpiryDate,
    PaygateRef.ItemsChoiceType.CardNumber
};

Request.Items = new string[] { "012020", "500000000000008" };
```

Comment: I am having this same problem now, but in VB, have you manage to solve this Validation error issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by changing the order of card details. In your case, you have put cardexpirydate above cardnumber. I reversed the order and also ensured that the cvv comes after card details. This will be your code.

```
Request.ItemsElementName = new PaygateRef.ItemsChoiceType[]
{
    PaygateRef.ItemsChoiceType.CardNumber,
    PaygateRef.ItemsChoiceType.CardExpiryDate

};

Request.Items = new string[] { "500000000000008", "012020" };

Request.CVV = "001";// card ccv
```

Hope it helps!!!

Also I did not use cardissuedate or cardissuenumber as these are optional and i didn't need.

In addition, you can also check the Details node of the exception that you get. In the details node, it will clearly define the cause of the error.

Answer (score -1):

CardIssuenumber is actually not the card's number and it's optional. had to scratch my head a bit for payhost structure : here is some of the validation you missing? hope this help

```
request.ItemsElementName = new payhostReference.ItemsChoiceType[] 
{
    payhostReference.ItemsChoiceType.CardExpiryDate,
    payhostReference.ItemsChoiceType.CardNumber
};

request.Items = new string[] { "122017", "4000000000000002"};
```

Comment: I get what you are saying. but i tried this and it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

A much simplier approach with very easy code to follow do the following.

1. import Nuget restsharp

   Imports RestSharp
   Imports System
   Imports System.Data
   Imports System.Configuration
   Imports System.Linq
   Imports System.Web
   Imports System.Web.Security
   Imports System.Web.UI
   Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
   Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
   Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
   Imports System.Xml.Linq
   Imports System.Net
   Imports System.Collections.Specialized
   Imports System.Text
   Imports WebApplication1.ServiceReference1

   Public Class _Default
   'Inherits Page
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
   Dim CheckSum As String
   Dim PaymentRequestId As String
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   ```
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Paygate()

        Response.Write(PaygateForm().ToString)
        Me.PaygatePostScript(Page)


    End Sub

    Private Sub PaygatePostScript(ByVal Page As System.Web.UI.Page)
        'This registers Javascript to the page which is used to post the Netcash Form details
        Dim strScript As New StringBuilder()
        strScript.Append("<script language='javascript'>")
        strScript.Append("var ctlForm = document.getElementById('Paygate');")
        strScript.Append("ctlForm.submit();")
        strScript.Append("</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "PPSubmit", strScript.ToString)

    End Sub


    Private Function PaygateForm()
        Dim client = New RestClient("https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/process.trans")
        client.Timeout = -1
        Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", "paygate_payweb3=u9tjr031eluc6jsflq952uatup")
        request.AddParameter("PAY_REQUEST_ID", PaymentRequestId)
        request.AddParameter("CHECKSUM", CheckSum)
        Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)


        Dim ppForm As New StringBuilder
        '<form action="https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/process.trans" method="POST" >
        ppForm.Append("<Form method=" + """" + "post" + """" + """" + " id=" + """" + "Paygate" + """" + " action=" + """" + "https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/process.trans" + """" + ">")
        ppForm.Append(response.Content.ToString)

        Return ppForm.ToString


    End Function
    Private Sub Paygate()
        Dim client = New RestClient("https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/initiate.trans")
        client.Timeout = -1
        Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", "paygate_payweb3=u9tjr031eluc6jsflq952uatup")
        request.AddParameter("PAYGATE_ID", "10011072130")
        request.AddParameter("REFERENCE", "pgtest_123456789")
        request.AddParameter("AMOUNT", "3299")
        request.AddParameter("CURRENCY", "ZAR")
        request.AddParameter("RETURN_URL", "https://my.return.url/page")
        request.AddParameter("TRANSACTION_DATE", "2018-01-01 12:00:00")
        request.AddParameter("LOCALE", "en-za")
        request.AddParameter("COUNTRY", "ZAF")
        request.AddParameter("EMAIL", "customer@paygate.co.za")
        request.AddParameter("CHECKSUM", "59229d9c6cb336ae4bd287c87e6f0220")
        Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
        CheckSum = response.Content.ToString

        Dim array1 As String() = CheckSum.Split("&")
        CheckSum = array1(3)
        CheckSum = Replace(CheckSum, "CHECKSUM=", "")
        PaymentRequestId = array1(1)
        PaymentRequestId = Replace(PaymentRequestId, "PAY_REQUEST_ID=", "")
        ' GetCheckSumPayGate()

    End Sub
   ```

   End Class

Comment: Please re-format your post to make the source code readable.