# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' when making http request via service reference

Tags: c#, .net, http, wcf, soap-client

I am doing a paygate integration (https://www.paygate.co.za), but when I attempt to make a call via the Payhost service reference, it appears that something is blocking my request?

---

Here is the exception

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: **The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.**
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

---

Here is my code (you can run this in a console app) the credentials for the API below are public information on the paygate API. I also want to point out that I have used and tested the below code in the past so I doubt its a code issue:

```
using PayHOSTService; //https://secure.paygate.co.za/payhost/process.trans?wsdl
try {
  PayGateAccountType PaygateAccount = new PayGateAccountType();
  PaygateAccount.PayGateId = "10011072130"; //Public Test Credentials
  PaygateAccount.Password = "secret"; //Public Test Credentials

  OrderType OrderType = new OrderType();
  OrderType.Amount = Convert.ToInt32(50 * 100);
  OrderType.Currency = CurrencyType.ZAR;
  OrderType.MerchantOrderId = "TestOrder";
  OrderType.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now;
  OrderType.Locale = "en-za";

  PersonType User = new PersonType();
  User.FirstName = "name";
  User.LastName = "Surname";
  User.Email = new string[1];
  User.Email[0] = "avalidemail@gmail.com";

  AddressType Address = new AddressType();
  Address.AddressLine = new string[1];
  Address.Country = CountryType.ZAF;
  Address.CountrySpecified = true;
  User.Address = Address;

  BillingDetailsType BillingDetails = new BillingDetailsType();
  BillingDetails.Address = Address;
  BillingDetails.Customer = User;
  OrderType.BillingDetails = BillingDetails;

  RedirectRequestType Redirect = new RedirectRequestType();
  Redirect.ReturnUrl = "http://localhost:44337/Payment/ReturnClient";
  Redirect.NotifyUrl = "http://localhost:44337/Payment/Notify";
  WebPaymentRequestType WebPaymentRequest = new WebPaymentRequestType();
  WebPaymentRequest.Account = PaygateAccount;
  WebPaymentRequest.Order = OrderType;
  WebPaymentRequest.Customer = User;
  WebPaymentRequest.Redirect = Redirect;
  WebPaymentRequest.PaymentType = new PaymentType[1];

  SinglePaymentRequest Request = new SinglePaymentRequest();
  Request.Item = WebPaymentRequest;

  //The request is sent here
  PayHOSTClient PayhostClient = new PayHOSTClient();
  SinglePaymentResponse1 Response = await PayhostClient.SinglePaymentAsync(Request);
  WebPaymentResponseType WebPaymentResponse =
    (WebPaymentResponseType) Response.SinglePaymentResponse.Item;

  Console.Write(WebPaymentResponse);
} catch (Exception Ex) {
  Console.Write(Ex);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

---

What I have tried:

- I have tried to run this on Mac (macOS Monterey) and Windows (11)
- I have tried the code in a console app (.net 6 (also tried .NET Framework 4.7.2)) and in an MVC project (.net core 3.1)
- I have tried this on 2 different networks (home and mobile)

What is the issue?

Comment: Another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973039/integration-with-paygate-in-asp-net/43466505)?

Comment: Similar yes, the difference with my integration is that I'm not sending any card details. Im just redirecting the client to paygate so that they can handle the entire transaction. Ill mess around with the order of things a bit and have another look through the API to make sure I haven't missed anything. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290464/how-to-fix-the-http-request-was-forbidden-with-client-authentication-scheme-an) to find a solution.